# unable to get data from belongsto relation keeping foreign key and local key as mongodb object id using mongodb laravel jessenger

Tags: mongodb, laravel, belongs-to

In my controller:-
$data = Favouriteignored::with('favusers');

In my Model Favouriteignored

```
public function favusers() {
     return $this->belongsTo('Usermanage', 'type_member_id','_id');
}
```

Collection favouriteignoredmembers document:-

```
{

"__v": NumberInt(0),  
"_id": ObjectId("54e5dce5b1e7b4018aa6ea86"),  
 "type": {
 "favourite": "1",
 "ignored": "0"
},  
 "type_member_id": ObjectId("54a5360be1f44e1e378b4567"),  
 "user_id": ObjectId("54b6162cf56c0de40e8b4567")  
}
```

members collection document :-

```
{
 "_id": ObjectId("54a5360be1f44e1e378b4567"),   
 "active": "1",
 "address": "test",
 "cell_number": "8888",
 "city": "test",
 "company": "test",
 "confirmation_code": "u74Vs0xJXna5RHZQz7DZTnY2XfKNzH",
 "country": "India",
 "department": "t",
 "email": "g@g.com",
 "first_name": "Gaurav",
 "gender": "male",
 "image": "52759b.jpg",
 "image_name": "",
 "is_deleted": "0",
 "last_login": "2015/02/19 12:50:07",
 "last_name": "handa",
 "password":   "$2y$10$fm0KsS0MX50VRWC9HIiTAumU5FU1qZIztxCkn/e9dbZuF2Tf7PwBy",
 "remember_token": "hN4n8eGALMXTs84Tub0qrgnqVlrDd1WDBHcKh8VDBLFs43wRA4GILL3OJDiy",
 "state": "test",
 "telephone_number": "123",
 "title": "t",
 "username": "t",
 "verified": "1",
 "via": "login",
 "zip_code": "test"
}
```

Now I am relating favouriteignored collection with member collection on the basis of "type_member_id" of favouriteignoredmembers as foreign key and _id of members collection.

Using foreign key and local key both as ObjectId of mongodb.
Unable to get results. It works fine if I keep type_member_id as string.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I think it might be a bug. I have noticed that also my relationships work well when the foreign key is a string. The ObjectId works sometimes but not all